# Area of the decagram and more generally, of star polygons

Tags: geometry, reference-request, area, polygons

I observed that the area of the decagram given on [Polytope wiki](https://polytope.miraheze.org/wiki/Decagram) is not correct: it is higher than the area of the circumcircle. Probably this value has be taken from [bendwavy.org](https://bendwavy.org/klitzing/dimensions/polygons.htm) where this is not the area but the *weighted* area which is given (it is defined on this page).

The decagram is a star polygon and it is claimed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_polygon) that these polygons have been intensively studied. However after googling I have not been able to find a formula for the area of the decagram.

So this question is merely a reference request: where can one find formulas for the area of a star polygon?

Comment: I think weighted area is the only meaningful definition for a star polygon.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Why? I'm currently playing with a geometry software and it returns the ordinary area, and I wanted to check it. My playing leisures are not important though ;-). What is the interest of the weighted area? If I pave my floor with decagrams, I want to know their areas, etc.

Comment: You can't pave your floor with decagrams. They're self-intersecting, unlike any real physical object. What you're thinking of is a concave 20-sided polygon, not a self-intersecting 10-sided polygon.

Comment: @mr_e_man Exactly. Thansk for the clarification. But then I want this area ^^

Comment: You can compute that area by yourself, from the coordinates of vertices on Polytope Wiki. By the way: I've just drawn a unit-side decagram with GeoGebra and its area is given  as 1.81635632, the same as on Polytope Wiki.

Comment: And the area of the concave 20-gon is given as 0.8596536241.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thanks. I know the decimal approximation, I computed it with CGAL.

Comment: So nobody replied to this question: what is the interest of a weighted area? (honnest question)